# key value match up

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

the above is what my gui looks like . on form load the sorted list displsys three randomly selected keys on the labels . the user then selects the corresponding value to match it with the key .

this is what i am struggling with ! below is how far i have gotten. please help !!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create the sorted list and add items
    SortedList<string,string> sl = new SortedList<string,string>();
    sl.Add("PicknPay", "jam");
    sl.Add("Spar", "bread");
    sl.Add("Checkers", "rice");
    sl.Add("Shoprite", "potato");
    sl.Add("Cambridge", "spinash");

    //declare random variable
    var rnd = new Random();
    var shuffledKeys = sl.Keys.OrderBy(key => rnd.Next()).ToList();

    lbl1.Text = shuffledKeys[0];
    lbl2.Text = shuffledKeys[1];
    lbl3.Text = shuffledKeys[2];
}
```

this is how my current thinking is help me match the label output with the combobox selection to confirm that the are in fact a valid key value pair

```
private void btnmatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    //match 
    if (sl.keys.Containskey(shuffledKeys[0]) || sl.value.Containsvalue(cb1.SelectedValue))
    {
        count++; //score                 
    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing
    }        
}
```

Comment: Where's that "sl" coming from?  It was declared local to the load method.

Comment: sl is name of the sortedlist declared in the pageload

Comment: You mean Form Load.  Like I said, it's declare local to that method.  The "sl" you are referencing in the click method is a different list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just select 3 random indexes into the sorted array, populate labels with values at these indexes and match them later by the keys?

Comment: @VictorHavin show me coz i could not get that to work for me at all .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like the code below? It is not clear if keys in labels should be unique. If they do, you should add one more loop to select a unique random number.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Label[] labels;
        private ComboBox[] combos;
        private Random r = new Random();
        SortedList<string, string> sl = new SortedList<string, string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labels = new Label[]{ label1, label2, label3 };
            combos = new ComboBox[]{ comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
            sl.Add("Key1", "Value1");
            sl.Add("Key2", "Value2");
            sl.Add("Key3", "Value3");
            sl.Add("Key4", "Value4");
            sl.Add("Key5", "Value5");

            HashSet<int> used = new HashSet<int>();

            foreach (Label l in labels)
            {
                int n = r.Next(0, sl.Count);
                while(used.Contains(n))
                   n = r.Next(0, sl.Count);
                used.Add(n);
                l.Text = sl.ElementAt(n).Key;
            }
            foreach(ComboBox combo in combos)
            {
                foreach(string s in sl.Values)
                {
                    combo.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int nCorrect = 0;

            for(int n = 0; n < labels.Length; n++)
            {
                if(combos[n].Text == sl[labels[n].Text])
                {
                    nCorrect++;
                }

            }
            labelScore.Text = nCorrect.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just in case: I have edited this code to select only unique keys.

Comment: true the keys in labels are supposed to be unique ... question why does the combobox create duplicates of values when it loads .

Comment: thank you . you have been kind enough to help with a problems thats been on my hands for a week. as a student i have learned simplicity from your code.

Comment: I changed the code to use only unique keys. What do you mean by "duplicates" in the combo boxes? If you mean that combo box values should be random (not in the order they were added to the sorted list), you can shuffle them. In general, randomizing just keys should be enough, as it makes keys in the form different from values.

Comment: I am glad if this was of any help. Good luck with your study.